# How to communicate to QWidget's slots through standard C++ class?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a standard c++ class, and I want one of its functions to communicate with a Qt widget's slot.

Lets say I have a function foo() in my C++ class, and I want that when ever this function gets called it signal to QWidget for corresponding slot. Since QWidget is used for display purposes 
and the standard C++ class is doing something else and I want to changes visual based upon some conditions( i.e. when foo() gets called).

Is it feasible that I can make a C++ class function to trigger a slot of QWidget class?

Comment: Slots are ordinary member functions.

Comment: So I can call slots of QWidgets w/o using connect()/signals?
sorry for seemingly obvious questions, very new to Qt.

Comment: Yes, you can. `someWidget->someSlot();`

Comment: You cannot connect a slot with a standard class method as signal. Unlike slots which are ordinary methods, signals are not. Signals are special members that can only defined in a QObject.

Comment: Additionally, any signal or slot can be called using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. But this is more related to metaprogramming than to general tasks.